# Redirect domain using https to cname domain

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, https, cname-record

I'm having an issue redirecting a domain to a new CNAME domain, basically my site `https://www.example.com` is now pointing to `sub.newsite.com` (using https) so I went to the htaccess file and added a new rule to redirect users using https to my new domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://id.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

I added a new SSL for my new domain (works fine when typed) and added the rule to redirect the https connections I think this is the right one but I keep getting and SSL error saying that SSL doesn't match.

1. My understanding is that htaccess will overwrite the URL before hitting the SSL certificate.
2. Do I need a special SSL for CNAMES?

Comment: "My understanding is that htaccess will overwrite the URL before hitting the SSL certificate." Your understanding is completely wrong.

Comment: Acquire a SAN certificate that has both domains under it.  Also, CNAME does not provide anything for https.

Comment: A bit late but can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935229/cname-ssl-certificates